# How do I take user to root file on completion of a function?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my app I have a button to log the user out. This runs an API that deletes their session and also it takes their session key out of user defaults.

This means they cannot access API's in the app. But after the log out has occurred, I want the user to be taken to the Register() view. In my ContentView(), I have an if statement that checks if they have a session key, if the user doesn't, Register() is presented.

I need to make it so that whenever there is no session key, Register() is presented. Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let keyString = defaults.string(forKey: "sessionKey") {
            
            MainPage()
                                    
        } else {
            Register()
                        
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct LogOutView: View {
    
    @StateObject var loginModel = LoginViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
                                
        VStack {
                                    
            Button(action: {
                print("Log Out Tapped...")
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                let keyString = defaults.string(forKey: "sessionKey") ?? ""
                
                loginModel.logOut(key: keyString ) { success in
                    
                    if success {
                        // Successfully logged out, remove the "key" from UserDefaults
                        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "sessionKey")
                    }
                }
                
            }, label: {
                
                Text("Log Out")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

If ContentView ran again after the log out I would have no problems but I am not sure that is a good method.

How can I do this?

Tried NavigationLinks, but this can cause problems in the users navigation flow

Comment: This might be a good candidate for [NavigationPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationpath)

Comment: @vadian I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require iOS16

Comment: Use `AppStorage` or `KeyChain` for a much safer option